# About protecting the time and energy of a startup team against the irresponsibility of academic growth centers or private accelerators

Tags: internet, professional-ethics

I have seen some rejection about my and other startups project form the Startup accelerator or Academic incubator, which is taking the team's works and energy.

For example, I have one green startup which have described [**here**](https://elasa2next.medium.com/introducing-the-initial-idea-of-a-project-in-the-field-of-waste-management-through-cyberspace-d888f853b7c0) and have high priority because of nature problems and ...,  but I am working on it alone for 6 months.
This startup has been hampered, Despite receiving **the award and second place in an academic entrepreneurship event** and [the open source nature](https://github.com/Startup-Data/Satluneh) of the programs with low resource request which is only a few students asking for cooperation or efficiency in order to implement the plan and not asking for the involvement of money investment or location of accelerators at the time of execution and team Construction by the university or other accelerators.

So that after about 6 months I have come to the conclusion that fulling the forms and participation in these events will not necessarily lead to a specific result ( creating teams).

For this reason, my question is about documenting and publishing the reasons for the lack of cooperation of the accelerator, in other words, debugging the behavior of the companies involved (accelerators, etc.)

Since the publication of correspondence information or the reasons for the rejection of this startup or others startups involves legal and ethical consideration, I have asked this question here.

I can do it by below methods and publishing the results of contacting with an academic entrepreneurship or Private accelerator companies on the internet (like medium site!):

- Informing the accelerator and obtaining permission about the publishing the result of the reasons for the rejection of the startup and the time spent for these correspondences and filling out forms
- Obtain final permission from the accelerator to publish information by recording the spoken words or ...
- or ...

So I have asked here for some advice on how to behave properly in these letters.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with the law.

Comment: This site is not for specific legal advice.

Comment: I have seen this post about the **[Where to ask about law, morality and ethics?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375175/where-to-ask-about-law-morality-and-ethics)** And there said : `Law SE is for legal questions, but note that asking for legal advice on a specific matter is explicitly off-topic.` So if this SE forum is not proper for this kind of question, I hope to be a guide to some proper forum to ask this question there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about law.

Comment: Try Workplace? They have lots of ethics questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is about documenting and publishing the reasons for the lack of cooperation of the accelerator

It is not entirely clear what your actual question is. Your concern seems to be how you can obtain authorization to publish the accelerator's/center's reason(s) for rejecting your application.

You don't need that authorization unless the accelerator's/center's terms & conditions require the applicant to comply with some secrecy rule. Your description does not reflect that any such rule is in place, but only you can ascertain that from the T&Cs.

The legality of "*recording the spoken words*" depends on whether your jurisdiction is under the "one-party consent" rule. If so, you don't need the counterparty's permission to record your conversation with it (and the previous paragraph would apply). If the two-party consent applies, you will need to obtain first the counterparty's consent to record the oral communications.

It is otherwise unclear what "*legal and ethical consideration*" you have in mind.